# Passing value from class back to form

Tags: c#, forms, class

So I making tic tac toe. In main file (Form1.cs) I want to have only button1_click,button2_click events in which I would call function from Class1. My problem is that I'm having loop so debuger returns error SystemStackOverflowException unhandelded.

Form1.cs:

```
    Form1 frm1;
    Class1 cl;
    public Form1()
    {
        cl = new Class1();
        frm1 = this;
        InitializeComponent();
    }



    private void button5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)  //gumb za tip1 igro
    {
       cl.button1funkcija(frm1);
    }
```

Class1.cs

```
Form1 form = new Form1(); //its needed so i can use it in my own made functions (prehod_stan2())
    public void button1funkcija (Form1 form)
    {
        if (form.numericUpDown2.Value != 0) 
        {
            form.label10.Text = "Preostale igre:" + form.numericUpDown2.Value;
            tip = 3;
            st_iger = form.numericUpDown2.Value;
            prehod_stran2();
            form.errorProvider6.Clear();
            stanje();
        }
        else //če je število iger enako 0, prikaži napako
        {
            form.errorProvider5.Clear();
            form.errorProvider6.SetError(form.numericUpDown2, "Število more biti večje od 0");
        }
    }

    public void prehod_stran2()  
    {
        if (form.textBox1.Text == "")
        {
            form.errorProvider1.SetError(form.textBox1, "Polje mora biti izpolnjeno");
            if (form.textBox2.Text == "")
                form.errorProvider2.SetError(form.textBox2, "Polje mora biti izpolnjeno");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Your code is missing the event handlers button1_click and button2_click and it is also missing the part of Class1 that's being called. There is no way we can help you without that information.

Comment: The `Form1 form = new Form1();` line is where you are probably going wrong. You do not want a new instance of the form - you want to use the existing instance. You would pass the instance of the form to the `Class1` constructor.

Comment: Probelm is that code is preety huge, i'm not sure why would u need button1 and button2 click,they dont even exsits (names are reserved for something else that comes later)

Comment: @Enigmativity Yes but how ? now i have it beacouse i can use form. in own made functions,beacouse if i do it like in button1funkcija then i need to take parameter when calling function (for example prehod_stran2)

Comment: @user3421357 - When you call the code `cl = new Class1();` you need to change it to `cl = new Class1(this);` to pass the reference to the form through to `Class1`. Of course you need to add the right constructor method in `Class1`. The passed reference then replaces the `new Form1()` code in `Class1`.

Comment: where is your loop code?

Comment: @Enigmativity Thank you very mmuch, its working. Would give u rep, for some reason cant see +

Comment: @user3421357 - I've added my comments as an answer. You can upvote/accept them there. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Form1 form = new Form1();` line is where you are probably going wrong. You do not want a new instance of the form - you want to use the existing instance. You would pass the instance of the form to the `Class1` constructor.

When you call the code `cl = new Class1();` you need to change it to `cl = new Class1(this);` to pass the reference to the form through to `Class1`. Of course you need to add the right constructor method in `Class1`. The passed reference then replaces the `new Form1()` code in `Class1`.

Comment: @user3421357 : Do not create new instance of 'Form1', just access your functions ('prehod_stan2()') by the form parameter in 'public void button1funkcija (Form1 form)'.

You can also opt the approach as specified above by Enigmativity.

Additionally you are creating same named object for 'Form1' i.e. 'form', which may be the probable cause of the exception.